# Spring Security 3.0- Customise basic http Authentication Dialog

Tags: grails, spring-security

Rather than reading;

A user name and password are being requested by http://localhost:8080. The site says: "Spring Security Application"

I want to change the prompt, or at least change what the "site says". Does anyone know how to do this via resources.xml?

In my Grails App Spring configuration, my current version is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <http-basic/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't change it. Your application sends to the browser only the "Spring Secuirty Application" part. Other parts of the prompt are added by you browser.

To change the "Spring Security Application" part, you can use `realm` attribute of the `<http>` element:

```
<http realm = "My Application" ... >
```